# Relation between ec2 and rds

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm studying RDS, and I have a question.

I'm reading in some places that rds relies on the ec2 infrastructure. But I don't understand why, what is the relation with rds and ec2?

I know that after we create an rds instance we can connect to rds instance from a ec2 instance, but what is the other relation?

For example, when we create a RDS instance we need to choose a db intance class, for example "db.t1.micro", but when we create an rds instance we dont create an ec2 instance...

So what I'm thinking is that maybe rds relies on ec2 infrastructure, because when we create an rds instance we are using the same ec2 infrastructure to create an instance but in this case for RDS? Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct, I think what they are really saying is that RDS instances run on the same infrastructure as the EC2 instances you spinup and use yourself.

When you start an RDS instance, it runs on an EC2 instance, but you have no access to that underlying instance it is controlled and managed by the RDS group/system.